# The best way to perform actions on GridView rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am attempting to perform an action on rows in a `GridView`.  From what I have read online, there are several ways to perform such actions.  All of these methods seem very convoluted and so much manual plumbing is involved.

For example, in order to "Delete" an item from a `GridView`, I've come across these methods:

**1: Using the `GridView` `RowCommand` event:**

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gridviewRow = 
        CoordinateFilesGridView.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
    MyEntity entity = (MyEntity)gridviewRow.DataItem;

    if(e.CommandName.Equals("Delete"))
    {
        // Perform delete action
        Delete(entity);
    }
}
```

**2: Providing an `OnClick` event to the "Delete" button**

```
public void Delete_Clicked(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((sender as WebControl).NamingContainer as DataListItem);
    var rowID = int.Parse(((HiddenField)item.FindControl("rowID")).Value);

    GridViewRow gridviewRow = CoordinateFilesGridView.Rows[rowID];
    MyEntity entity = (MyEntity)gridviewRow.DataItem;

    // Perform delete action
    Delete(entity);
}
```

**3: Linking to a URL and breaking the querystring down in the `Page_Load`**

```
if (queryString != null && queryString["action"] != null)
{
    if (queryString["action"].Equals("delete") && queryString["rowID"] != null)
    {
        GridViewRow gridviewRow = 
            CoordinateFilesGridView.Rows[(int)queryString["rowID"]];
        MyEntity entity = (MyEntity)gridviewRow.DataItem;

        // Perform delete action
        Delete(entity);
    }
}
```

How would you perform such an action? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Providing an OnClick event to the "Delete" button. Because on RowCommand every time it's check delete operation for all row

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi `RowCommand` doesn't check all rows, only the clicked row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with either 1 or 2 based on your own preference.

I would usually go with option 1 just because it is the built in `GridView` button handler, so if you have multiple buttons within your rows, you have one method for handling these and you are reusing the code -

```
GridViewRow gridviewRow = 
    CoordinateFilesGridView.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
MyEntity entity = (MyEntity)gridviewRow.DataItem;
```

Rather than adding multiple click events and possibly adding this code below to the individual click methods.

```
var item = ((sender as WebControl).NamingContainer as DataListItem);
var rowID = int.Parse(((HiddenField)item.FindControl("rowID")).Value);
```

At the end of the day though, it is really just your own preference. I have used 1 and 2 on multiple occasions. I cannot see any reason why you would want to use 3.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Gridview to perform the actions such as delete or update, for the easiest method i know is to use the quicktasks menu at the right hand side of the gridview.

1) Click the Edit columns
2) click commandField
3) then add an delete update and cancel button to gridview to delete rows.

view smart method lessons of asp.net at youtube.. hope that is useful..

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the GridView's `RowDeleting` event? It will only fire when a row's Delete button is clicked, so you can skip the step where you're currently checking `e.CommandName`.
Also, you'll be able to examine `e.Keys` to get the Id of the entity you want to delete (assuming you've set the GridView's `DataKeyNames` property).

```
<asp:GridView ID="CoordinateFilesGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDeleting="CoordinateFilesGridView_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


protected void CoordinateFilesGridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    var entityId = int.Parse(e.Keys["Id"].ToString());

    DeleteEntity(entityId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> In short, whatever works for you in the current situation.
> ```

You can avoid the plumbing code, if you use a Data access layer with decorated methods for Insert, Update, Delete. You just have to specify the methods on your datasource & everything should work out of the box.

Inside my Business Logic layer I have these methods which hit the DAL

```
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
    public static int UpdateItem(EmployeeItem myItem)
    {
        return EmployeeDB.UpdateItem(myItem);
    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)]
    public static bool DeleteItem(EmployeeItem myItem)
    {
        return EmployeeDB.DeleteItem(myItem.EmployeeID);
    }
```

On my presentation layer I have the object datasource bind to these

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsSecCh" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="myCompany.myProject.BO.EmployeeItem"
  DeleteMethod="DeleteItem" InsertMethod="SaveItem" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
 SelectMethod="GetListById" TypeName="myCompany.myProject.BLL.EmployeeManager">
  <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="empId" Type="Int32" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

This way, no plumbing code is required on other aspx pages where you use the same gridview control.